# Growing Access Frontend: Should I be concerned?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I've read opinions across the internet that say if you design or MS Access FrontEnd properly, it shouldn't shrink too much when you do a compact. I've got one front end I'm using that is typically around 15 MB when compacted, but grows to 20-25 MB while I'm working on it! Is this something I should be concerned about?

Comment: By working, do you mean editing forms or updating and adding data?

Comment: Is it creating or deleting any tables inside itself?

Comment: Remou: Editing and creating forms/reports
.
PowerUser: It's just the front end so there should be no new tables

EDIT: Oh, I also edit modules too.

Comment: Where do you get this "it shouldn't shrink too much"? This seems to me to be backwards of what most experienced developers would say -- a properly-designed front end won't *grow* much beyond a certain point during regular use.

Comment: Growth during development work on the front end is to be expected, but is completely outside the point that people are making when they make statements about what to expect of a properly-designed front end. It's the front ends on the end users' desktops that won't grow much, i.e., when in production use. While you're developing it, of course there's going to be lots of growth -- it's to be expected, and not at all what anyone is talking about when discussing bloat and properly-designed front ends.

Comment: I definitely took it the wrong way then. I thought what people were saying was that a frontend that shrinks when compacted was a bad thing, whether it was still being made or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are adding reports and so on, I do not think you should be concerned. I suggest that you decompile* fairly regularly when you are working on code, forms and reports.

---

* http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Decompile

Comment: I tried decompiling through a shortcut using "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\MSACCESS.EXE" "\\Users\Database\DB.mdb" /decompile  before but it seemed to just open the database and the size of it didn't change at all which I found strange. So I'm not sure that way worked. I'll try the method at lessthandot later in the day and see what happens.

Comment: It is the same thing as the switch you used - it is just useful for drag-and-drop. You might like to try the decompile followed by compact & repair - it usually works best. However, your front-end will grow when code and objects are added.

Comment: Ok, I just wasn't sure if it was unhealthy for a front end to grow 7-10 MB while working on it. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you keep regular back-ups - even a quick copy can save a lot of grief if a form suddenly becomes unusable. It can be an idea to copy to a fresh MDB if you make a lot of changes, because, for example, the number of controls allowed for the life of a form includes deleted controls.

Comment: I do keep backups which have saved me in the past. I had no idea there was a limit to the number of controls on a form! I have created a fresh MDB and copied everything over, but this will definitely persuade me to do that more often!

Answer (score 4):

There is a distinction between development and production use.

1. during development, bloat should be expected -- you're churning the data pages in your front end, revising forms, reports, modules, etc., so there will be frequent discarding of data pages. There is nothing wrong with this. During development, you should compact regularly, and occasionally decompile (not often -- I tend to do it maybe once a day during heavy development, and/or immediately before distributing a new front end into production use).
2. during production use, a properly-designed front end should not bloat much. Yes, when you supply a compiled and compacted front end, it will grow some during use, but after a while, that growth should top off. But you shouldn't be concerned about that, as front ends are fungible. If something goes wrong with one, you just replace it with a new one.

The most common reason people encounter bloat in front ends is because they design them incorrectly, including temporary data in their front end (e.g., a table that has data appended to it that is then deleted). Temp data belongs in a temp file. All of my apps have a tmp.mdb that is distributed along with the front end and stored in the same folder as the front end, and all temporary data is stored there. I generally never bother to compact temp files.

Other sources of bloat might include:

1. design changes to forms/reports made in code (which would be the same in terms of bloat as the human developer making the same changes). This is almost always a design error, in my opinion.
2. changes to saved QueryDefs in the app. This one is less significant, as the amount of bloat is quite small compared to other types of bloat. However, if this is being done thousands of times in a session, it could theoretically reach the level of significance. There are a few good reasons to edit saved QueryDefs at runtime, but not very many, so while I wouldn't call doing this a design error, it would be a red flag that it needed to be checked to make sure it's not something that can be accomplished efficiently without editing the saved QueryDef.

Answer (score -1):

Growing Front-End? To stupid to be true but it works. My database is used (through the cloud) by several companies and therefore the application can hardly ever be closed for compression (The last one to leave puts the lights out: compresses the database). My customers need to be online in the database all of the time. In less than one week the front-end used to grow from 16Mb to over 2Gb! This was scaring the hell out of me.
Solution: In the file explorer, simply right-click the front-end database, click 'properties' and check the 'read-only'-box.
Access will try to write the enlarged front-end but does not crash on the read-only flag. Again: just to simple to be true!
Best regards, Jaap Schokker, miniPLEX B.V., Wageningen, Holland